# glyphicon calendar is hiding inside the cell

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I will try to use Eonasdan Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker. Here the calendar is open but it is hiding inside the cell. I can't able to select the date. I have given
z-index also. But still its not displaying outside the cell.

[image]

And datetimepicker calendar opened in top. When I click picker, the calender will open in bottom of the datetimepicker.

Comment: can you create a fiddle reproducing the issue?

Comment: For outside grid and toolbar its working fine. Inside the cell only its not working. The calendar is hiding inside the cell.

Comment: Hence a fiddle would help...I don't know if setting the cells overflow to visible would help. I looked at the plugin and it doesn't appear there's a way to append it to the body instead of the element...